# How would I go about ignoring certain code in a HTML file, from another HTML file?

Tags: html

This may seem like an unconventional thing to ask, but I was wondering if it is possible to alter certain code (e.g. `<title>blah blah blah</title>` in file1.html, from file2.html? I want to ignore/cancel out that code from file2.html. I know you would just open up file1.html and use `<!--<title>blah blah blah</title>-->` to hide that, but is that possible to do from file2.html? This is just purely a hypothetical question.

Thanks,

Comment: is file 2 going to be contained in file 1? or are they independant files?

Comment: file2 can be contained in file1, yes.

Comment: Let me reiterate, file2 will definitely be contained/sourced in file1.

Comment: However, changes to file 1 must not be physically made through file1, but through file2.

Answer (score 0):

There is a important thing to know, the application that is supposed to do that is online or local? If it's online I think it's probably not possible to alter a file for security reasons.
if it's local you can do that using some library responsible for the IO process. Like .NET framework use System.IO for things like that.

I hope it helps!